# Unity Ads cannot show ads: webapp not initialized

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityads

I downloaded the latest [Unity Ads SDK](https://github.com/Applifier/unity-ads-sdk) and followed the [instructions](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/integration-guide-android) to integrate it on my android app.

```
UnityAds.init(this, "xxxxxxx", null);
```

The initialization was successful and the log shows that the ad was downloaded.

```
Initializing Unity Ads version 1508 with gameId xxxxxxx

Requesting Unity Ads ad plan from https://xxxxxxx

Unity Ads initialized with 3 campaigns and 2 zones

Unity Ads cache: File /storage/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy.mp4 of 1445875 bytes downloaded in 9102ms
```

I try to show the ad:

```
if (UnityAds.canShow()) {
    UnityAds.show();
}
```

Then this error message appears:

```
Unity Ads cannot show ads: webapp not initialized
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the `IUnityAdsListener` (third initialization parameter) is required and cannot be null.

The fix is to add the listener to the `init` method like below:

```
UnityAds.init(this, "xxxxxxx", new IUnityAdsListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onShow() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoCompleted(String s, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchCompleted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailed() {
    }
});
```